# Change the Value of a dynamically created JSON Object

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

i'm trying to change the value of an object with a button press.

(want to change the current value:

from
"Sort" : "List"

to
"Sort" : "Bank"

I'm not sure if I have to use a put or a patch, or if there is an easier way.  I think part of my problem is targeting the right div as there are a bunch of these created I'm not sure I'm using (this) correctly?

```
'use strict';

$(function() {

  var $chooseStores = $('#currentStores');
   var $availableStores = $('#availableStores');
  var $addStoresToList = $('.addStoreToList');
  var $removeStoreFromList = $('.removeStoreFromList');


$(document).on('click', '.removeStoreFromList', removeStore);

function removeStore() {
console.log(this);
$.ajax({
  type: 'PUT',
  url: '/stores/' + $(this).data('_id'),
  data: {
    sort: 'bank'
  }
}).done();
 }

 $.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '/stores',
success: function(stores) {
  $.each(stores, function(i, store) {
    if (store.sort === 'list') {
      $chooseStores.append(`<div class="fav-store">
        <div class="fav-store-img">
          <img 
          src="images/icons/grocery
              /icon-grocery-${store.name..toLowerCase()}.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="fav-store-name">
          <span class="storeSpan">${store.name}</span>
          <span class="storeSpan">${store._id}</span>
          <button class="removeStoreFromList smallButton">remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
        `)
        };
      });
    }
  });


});
```

Comment: "I'm not sure if I have to use a put or a patch"...that totally depends on how your server works, but you've told us exactly nothing about that. Check its documentation, or check with the maintainers, or, if it's your server-side app, check the code

Comment: "I'm not sure I'm using (this) correctly" - in that context, `this` will be the button which was clicked. But it doesn't have any "_id" or "data-_id" attribute on it, so I doubt it'll find a value to send. Did you debug any of this with your browser's Developer Tools?

Comment: Sorry I'm still learning best practices for debugging. 

I'm still trying to figure out how to just make it so a link will change the value of that sort key from "list" to "Bank" that would then put it in the correct filter.

Comment: if you just want to filter the list of stores you'd likely be making another GET request to the /stores URL, to get a reduced list. That would make most sense. Usually POST, PUT and PATCH are used to actually modify single items in the data store, not just change a search parameter. I say _likely_ because we cannot see your server code and have no idea what it expects/allows you to send, and what it will do when you send it.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, I want to modify the value of the "sort" key back and fourth from list to bank.  I already have filters set up to display the correct items based on that value, but I need a way to toggle that setting back and fourth. I'm doing this all in node / express / mongo mongoose / ajax and jquery  nothing special on the server side.

Comment: I'm sure it's nothing special, but that doesn't mean I know what format and types of data it expects to receive _in your unique application's case_. It sounds like basically in JS you need to have a variable to hold what the current filter setting is, and then when the button is clicked, make an AJAX request using GET (like the one you run initially) which changes the filter value, and then passes the value (or no filter, if the user desires and that's allowed) to the server in the parameters. So probably `$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '/stores', data: {
    sort: 'bank'
  }` or similar

Comment: ...but you'd replace the hard-coded "bank" string with a variable whose value was correctly set in your code based on what the user selected. Your example isn't clear enough for me to understand how it is that the user chooses between them, but I guess you can figure that out. And i said "or similar" because again, I cannot possibly know, without seeing the relevant server-side code, whether `{ "sort": "bank" }` is the way the server actually expects to receive a filter command, or not.